# Rounding the output Vector of a Neural Network layer to prepare it for the next layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am attempting to Round up the output Vector of a Neural Network layer to prepare it for the next layer
Ex. Layer output {.1.,2.2,3.3} and I need it to be a Vector of Integers for the next layer.

I have tried this,
Round@@LinearLayer[3]. But it does not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank You

Michel

Answer (score 4):

ElementwiseLayer[Ceiling] rounds up, ElementwiseLayer[Round] rounds to the nearest integer. This layer also accepts arbitrary compositions of a subset of Mathematica functions (see documentation for more details).

Comment: Hello,
When I run this:  a = ElementwiseLayer[Round]
a[{1.3, 4.6}]

MMA12 still gives reals
{2., 5.}

Am I missing some setting?

Comment: It's just how Mathematica's nerual functionality works internally: almost everything is floating point. For example, OrderingLayer should in theory return integers, just like Ordering does, but in fact its output is floating point. This is usually not a problem for further layers, though.